# Combo box com pesquisa

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, combobox

Preciso criar uma `combobox` que permita que o administrador pesquise o usuário e que enquanto  o administrador pesquisa, já apareça dentro da combo algumas opções que são similares ao que foi digitado. Além disso, depois de achar o usuário pesquisado, o administrador deve clicar na opção selecionada, e embaixo dela, exibir todos os dados do usuário.

Alguém sabe se é possível fazer? Se sim, poderiam postar um exemplo, mesmo que simples da aplicação?

Comment: Algo assim? http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Isso! Porém preciso popular essa combo box com os dados do banco, e depois exibir o dado selecionado em uma grid/form embaixo...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para implementar o Autocomplete, você precisará instalar o seguinte pacote:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.ui.combined/

Suponha uma `TextBox` com `Autocomplete` que traga cidades, e preencha automaticamente um estado de acordo com a Id do estado. Preciso ter na minha `View` os campos de cidade, estado, os hidden fields e o script que faz tudo isso funcionar:

```cs
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CityID)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StateID)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CityName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StateName, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#CityName").autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("AjaxFindByName", "Cities")',
            minLength: 3,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#CityName").val(ui.item.value);
                $("#CityID").val(ui.item.CityID);
                $("#StateName").val(ui.item.StateName);
                $("#StateID").val(ui.item.StateID);

                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

No Controller, precisamos ter uma `Action` que devolva um JSON para popular as informações do `Autocomplete`, recebendo um `term` como parâmetro (`term` neste caso é padrão do jQuery UI, e quer dizer que é parte do nome da cidade neste contexto):

```cs
    public JsonResult AjaxFindByName(string term)
    {
        var cities = context.Cities
            .Include(c => c.State)
            .Where(c => c.Name.ToUpper().Contains(term.ToUpper())).Take(10)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(c => new
            {
                value = c.Name,
                CityID = c.CityID,
                StateName = c.State.Name,
                StateID = c.StateID
            });

        return Json(cities, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```