# TextBox com Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Quero fazer com que uma `textbox` mostre-me os nomes dos usuários cadastrados no banco enquanto eu digito. Ex: se eu digitar a letra r, a `textbox` deve me mostrar algumas opções que contém a letra r, porém,  não estou conseguindo colocar pra funcionar. Será que eu esqueci algo?

Aqui está o código que estou utilizando:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#txtPesq").autocomplete({
                    source: '@Url.Action("pesquisarUsuario")',
                    minLength: 0
                });
            });
    </script>






<h2>Index</h2>


@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBox("pesquisa", null, new { id = "txtPesq" })
    <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" />



}
```

Comment: Estou utilizando asp.net mvc e não tenho nenhum formulário para auto.preenchimento. Apenas quero que minha textbox exiba os nomes conforme eu digito

Comment: Já respondi essa aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31799/combo-box-com-pesquisa/31805#31805.